# Second derivative of parametric equations

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

I am looking for an intuitive explanation for the formula used to take the second derivative of a parametric function. The formula is:

$\frac{\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$

I understand the reasoning for getting $\frac{dy}{dx}$-- by dividing $\frac{dy}{dt}$ by $\frac{dx}{dt}$ -- however I am lost in the above formula. If we are finding the second derivative of y with respect to x, why do we differentiate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with respect to t, but not $\frac{dx}{dt}$?

My inability to understand this could be due to my already fragile understanding of Leibnitz notation. At any rate, I would appreciate an explanation for why this formula is set up in this way.

Again, the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ part makes sense, we were finding the derivative of y with respect to x, and since both x and y are functions of t, we found how x changes with respect to t, and how y changes with respect to t, and divided them.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively (from Leibnitz notation):
$$
\frac{\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)\frac{dt}{dx}
=
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)
$$

Comment: Okay, so I see how the dt's cancel, creating the $\frac{d}{dx}$. But why is the numerator so different than the denominator. When finding the first derivative, it is just $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$, where the numerator and denominator are almost identical. Why is it that when you take the second derivative, the denominator looks so different from the numerator?

Comment: The intuitive rule ( that must be used with some care) is always the same: '' use the Leibnitz notation as a fraction'' (also if it is not really a fraction). So we write: $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$

Answer (score 1):

I asked my teacher and figured it out: since we want to find the derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we must find the derivative with respect to *x*, not t. Even though $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is in terms of *t*, when we find the derivative it *must* be with respect to *x*. This should make sense. If you wanted to find the derivative of 15x, you would apply the $\frac{d}{dx}$ operation, not something like $\frac{d}{dt}$ or $\frac{d}{dh}$ or any other variable. Since we now know we must use the $\frac{d}{dx}$ on $\frac{dy}{dx}$, it becomes clear that the $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ is the same as using $\frac{d}{dx}$, since the *dt*'s cancel.